# Regex validate PIN code JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve this task:

> ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain
>   anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.
>
> If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return
>   false.
>
> eg:
>
> validatePIN("1234") === true validatePIN("12345") === false
>   validatePIN("a234") === false

And this is my code:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  if(pin.length === 4 ||  pin.length === 6 ) {
    if( /[0-9]/.test(pin))  {
      return true;
    }else {return false;}
  }else {
      return false;
      }
}
```

It shows that --- Wrong output for 'a234' - Expected: false, instead got: true ---Why?  This /[0-9]/ shows only numbers?

Thank you in advance  :)

Comment: Because your test is asking, "is there a character that is a digit anywhere in this string"? Which is true for "a234".

Comment: Try this `/^\d{4}$/`

Comment: `const isValid = (pin) =>  /^(\d{4}|^\d{6})$/.test(pin)`

Comment: ahem... trying to cheat on codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/55f8a9c06c018a0d6e000132

lol, I was too looking for help on this one, you did better than me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/[0-9]/` will match any number in the string, so it matches the "2" in "a234". You need to make it match only numbers, from beginning to end: `/^[0-9]+$/` or `/^\d+$/`

Additionally, you can just use the regular expression `/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/` to match all strings containing 4 or 6 numbers.

```
/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test("1234"); // true
/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test("12345"); // false
/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test("123456"); // true
/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test("a234"); // false
```

Answer (score 7):

As you can see [in this regex example](https://regex101.com/r/iz4Ln7/3) `/[0-9]/` will match any string that has at least 1 number anywhere in it.

To fix this you can use quantifiers to match exactly either

- 4 numbers: `[0-9]{4}`
- 6 numbers: `[0-9]{6}`

Additionally, we want these regexes to actually match the entire string, using `^` at the start, and `$` at the end of the regex. This will make sure nothing exists next to a matched pin code.
If we combine the 2 cases above in a *capture group*, and add the start- and end-delimiters, we end up with this regex:

[**`/^([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})$/`**](https://regex101.com/r/iz4Ln7/2)

Note: the `[0-9]` character set has a nice shorthand: `\d`, so the regex could be further simplified to:

**`/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/`**

---

This single regex performs all the validation you need, so in your code `validatePIN` could be simplified as follows:

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
    return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin);
}

console.log(validatePIN('1234')); // > true
console.log(validatePIN('123456')); // > true
console.log(validatePIN('123')); // > false
console.log(validatePIN('12345')); // > false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex

^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{4}|.{6})$

Explanation

```
 ^ # Start of string
     (?= # Assert that the following regex can be matched here: 
    [0-9]* # any number of digits (and nothing but digits) 
    $ # until end of string ) # (End of lookahead) 
    (?: # Match either 
    .{4} # 8 characters | # or 
    .{6} # 11 characters ) # (End of alternation) 
    $ # End of string
```

Answer (score 1):

> Have a look at the code

```js
function validatePIN(pin) {
  if (/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(validatePIN("1234"));
console.log(validatePIN("a234"));
console.log(validatePIN("12345"));
console.log(validatePIN("123456"));
```

> Explanation:

1. You don't need to check the length manually, regex can do that, e.g. `{4} or {6}`
2. You can use `\d`, instead of `[0-9]`, it's a short hand
3. Plus regex needs to be end to end, i.e. with start and end should be specified with `^ ... $`

Comment: The question says the PIN can be either 4 or 6 digits. You only allow 4.

Comment: @Barmar I have added that as well

Comment: Why not do them in a single regexp: `/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/`?

Comment: @Barmar, Huried reply lead me to give a dirty fix, like I left 6 and next a simple or. Thank you for pointing those out.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not specifying where the number needs to be.

If there is a number in your expression it will be true that's all you are checking right now.

To correct that behavior you need to do this:

```
/^[0-9]+$/.test(pin)
```

With this you are saying that the "number" should start, contain and end in a number.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this regex `/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/` to validate pin.

```js
function validate(a){
    return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(a);
}

console.log(validate('1234'));
console.log(validate('123a'));
console.log(validate('1234a'));
console.log(validate('123412'));
```

Answer (score 1):

JAVA: Check each PIN number against an array of numbers and fill in a boolean loop accordingly. If the boolean loop in the end is not all true, return false.

```
public static boolean validatePin(String pin) {

String[] arr1 = pin.split("");
String[] num = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"};
boolean[] bool = new boolean[arr1.length];


if(arr1.length != 6 && arr1.length != 4){
  return false;
}



for(int i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j<num.length; j++){

        if(arr1[i].equals(num[j])){
            bool[i] = true;
        }

    }

}

for(int i = 0; i <bool.length; i++){

  if(bool[i] == false){
    return false;
  }

}

return true;
```

}

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer.