# Validate PIN w/ Javascript - SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, regex

These are the instructions: ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits. If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.

This is my code:

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  let regexPIN4 = /^\d{4}$/;
  let regexPIN6 = /^\d{6}$/;
  
  if (regexPIN4.test(pin)|regexPIN6.test(pin)){
      return True;
};
```

This is the error:

```
/home/codewarrior/index.js:47
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
```

I reviewed StackOverflow entry: [Regex validate PIN code JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179722/regex-validate-pin-code-js)

Comment: You did not close `if` block.

Comment: Aso, dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177143/regex-to-match-a-digit-two-or-four-times or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874777/regex-exactly-n-or-m-times

Comment: Was my question down-voted b/c of the dupe questions? Trying to understand this forum.

Answer (score 3):

- you were missing second `}`
- for logical OR you need two `||`.
- in javascript there is no `True`, only `true`

this should be the right code:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  let regexPIN4 = /^\d{4}$/;
  let regexPIN6 = /^\d{6}$/;

  return regexPIN4.test(pin) || regexPIN6.test(pin);
}
```

You can even simplify it like this:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  let regexPIN = /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/;

  return regexPIN.test(pin);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your syntax mistakes, here's a demo to get your task done with only one regex that allows only 4 or 6 digits.

```js
function checkPin(pin) {
  // regex to check for pins with 4 or 6 digits
  return /^\d{4}(\d{2})?$/.test(pin);
}

console.log(checkPin(1234)); // true
console.log(checkPin(123456)); // true
console.log(checkPin(12)); // false - not exactly 4 or 6 digits
console.log(checkPin('12h34')); // false - a non-digit character
```

About your mistakes:

- the logical `OR` operator in `JavaScript` is written like: `||` not
  `|`.
- You missed an `}` to close the `if` statement.
- And it's `true` not `True`, keep this in mind, `JavaScript` is **case-sensitive**.

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

8ADBO

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  let regexPIN4 = /^\d{4}$/;
  let regexPIN6 = /^\d{6}$/;
  
  if (regexPIN4.test(pin)|regexPIN6.test(pin)){
      return True;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).